# Select and build library

Tags: shared-libraries, qt-creator, qbs

Using Qt Creator to open and build a Qbs project, I can select what product I want to build in the bottom left panel (alongside the kit to use, and the selection of debug or release)

When I have more than one product of type "application" in a Qbs project, I can select which one I want to build.

But when one of the product is of type library, I can only select the products of type application. To build the library, I need to right click in the project tree.

Is there a way to make the library appear alongside the other products ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Qt Creator only shows Qbs targets which can be run. You cannot run a dynamic library.

Comment: that's what I thought